# pull-right doesn't exist in Angular Bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I noticed that `pull-right` is not working in the bootstrap version for angular, is this normal ? or there are other css classes that doesnt exist in that version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's changed to `float-right` in [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/):

```html
<div class="float-right">
  This text is on the right.
</div>
```